# Passing parameters to a JS function from HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I have s select list that should change an image when an option is selected. I have the following code:

```
<select id="p1_choise" onchange="change(image)">
  <option value=0>Choose</option>
  <option value=1>Rock</option>
  <option value=2>Paper</option>
  <option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>

<p><img src="rps.jpg" id="image"></p>
```

And then in my .ps file I have this:

```
function change(image) {
    var icon = document.getElementById("p1_choise").value;
    switch (parseInt(icon)) {
        case 1: document.getElementById(image).src="rock.jpg"; break;
        case 2: document.getElementById(image).src="paper.jpg"; break;
        case 3: document.getElementById(image).src="scissors.jpg"; break;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

The image parameter tells the function what image to change. There are other images that might be changed.

How do I pass a parameter correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the select has an id, you can separate the JavaScript and the HTML.

Comment: please change value="0" like this.

Comment: What is the image variable in the `onchange="change(image)"` representing? Is it an `id` of an `img` element on the page? Also, is it variable - by that I mean is there more than 1 image that you wish to change the `src` of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onchange` assignment, you have to specify the id value of the `img` element, that is a string. So you have to quote the argument:

```
<select id="p1_choise" onchange="change('image')">
  <option value=0>Choose</option>
  <option value=1>Rock</option>
  <option value=2>Paper</option>
  <option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById` to get image element in your `change` function

```
<select id="p1_choise" onchange="change()">
  <option value=0>Choose</option>
  <option value=1>Rock</option>
  <option value=2>Paper</option>
  <option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>

<p><img src="rps.jpg" id="image"></p>
```

JS:

```
    function change() {
       var image = document.getElementById("image");
        var icon = document.getElementById("p1_choise").value;
        switch (parseInt(icon)) {
            case 1: image.src="rock.jpg"; break;
            case 2:image.src="paper.jpg"; break;
            case 3: image.src="scissors.jpg"; break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to pass anything.

Comment: @Sushil: With the changes you mention you'll need to do 'case 1: image.src=".."', otherwise you'll get the same error.

Comment: @richardtz, sorry, I did not get your comments.

Answer (score -1):

A more generic js function will be like this (you can specify the select element and the image element)

```
<select id="p1_choise" onchange="change(this,document.getElementById('image'))">
  <option value=0>Choose</option>
  <option value=1>Rock</option>
  <option value=2>Paper</option>
  <option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>

<p><img src="rps.jpg" id="image"></p>

<script>
function change(options,imageElement) {
    var icon = options.value;
    switch (parseInt(icon)) {
        case 1: imageElement.src="rock.jpg"; break;
        case 2: imageElement.src="paper.jpg"; break;
        case 3: imageElement.src="scissors.jpg"; break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Updated so you can specify the image and the select elements as parameters

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="p1_choise" onchange="change(this)">
  <option value=0>Choose</option>
  <option value=1>Rock</option>
  <option value=2>Paper</option>
  <option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>

<p><img src="rps.jpg" id="image"></p>

function change(this) {
    var icon = this.value;
    switch (parseInt(icon)) {
        case 1: document.getElementById("image").src="rock.jpg"; break;
        case 2: document.getElementById("image").src="paper.jpg"; break;
        case 3: document.getElementById("image").src="scissors.jpg"; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The parameter tell the function what image to change, not what was selected....